# JQuery Custom Content Scroller Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollbar

I want to use Custom Content Scroller JQuery plugin on my Joomla 3 website, but it seems that it is not working.

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/blaa/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" type="text/css">
        <script data-rocketsrc="/templates/blaa/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js" type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketoptimized="true"></script>
<script>
        jQuery(window).ready(function($){
            $("#wrapper").mCustomScrollbar({
                theme:"light"
            });
            console.log("mCustomScrollbar started now!");
        });

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... });
</script>
```

I see console writes

```
mCustomScrollbar started now!
```

But scrollbar is the same and doesn't change.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `#wrapper` have a height css property (see http://jsfiddle.net/xHqFn/2/ for working example)?